# NGINX allow ONLY from a certain domain and certain IP (at the same time)

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have searched high and low for an answer to this an for the life of me can't find one, is it even possible?

What I need to do is:

Only allow connection to NGINX from a certain domain, and only allow connections to NGINX from a certain IP

So allow all conections coming in from the domain specified and the IP specified and return 444 for anything else

These need to be on the same NGINX instance.

If anyone can be a help here I would be very greatful

Thank You

Comment: You can try to achieve this with the 3rd party [rDNS module](https://github.com/flant/nginx-http-rdns), but I don't know if you can combine its rules with the native nginx `access`/`deny` directives.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that I am unable to install any new modules to the NGINX installation.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to build rules based on domain names without additional nginx modules. If you're using OpenResty, there can be a way to write something similar with the lua code. Otherwise I think it's impossible. Or maybe you can use firewall rules instead.